# Clustering and T-test (number of neurons in two groups of mice)

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, k-means, biostatistics, neuroimaging

I will present my problem to you.
I have a database of brain slides of 40 mice. There are two groups of mice, mice 1 and mice 2, and each of the groups is made up of 20 mice.
On each slide of the brain I have dots that represent the neurons of the mice (so mice do not necessarily have the same number of neurons, this number varies between 100 and 200).
I specify that the brains of the mice are normalized, i.e. aligned.

My problem is whether there are areas (groupings of neurons) that are different between the two groups. It is therefore necessary to first determine the zones and then test whether the number of neurons is different between the two groups.

First, I cut the brain map into a bin and counted the number of neurons per bin; then I did a t-test for each bin between the two groups.
But various problems appear with this method, on the one hand there is no result when correcting for multiple tests, then how to choose the size of the bins.

Secondly, I performed a K-means on all the neurons by omitting in the clustering the identifier of the mouse and its group. Once the clustering was done I counted the number of neurons per cluster and per mouse and I did a t-test to see if there were any significant differences. But here again there are problems, on the one hand when clustering we introduce a bias by omitting the information from the mice for the neurons and on the other hand how to choose the K of the K-means.

So there you go, I would have liked to know if any of you have any idea about my problem. Or if you know a method of clustering neurons taking into account the group and the mouse and doing t-tests simultaneously, that's a lot indeed (hahahaha).

Comment: Maybe treat it as a spatial problem, for each of the two groups, estimate the density of (number of neurons per area unit), and then compare this maps?  (And,make a more descriptive title ... I have proposed one as an edit!)

Comment: " on the one hand there is no result when correcting for multiple tests" - this sounds as if you see it as a problem if you don't get significance. But it shouldn't be. Tests can only be unbiased if you are prepared to accept the result as it is, including insignificance. If you look for another approach until you get significance, that significance is meaningless.

Comment: Also generally if you do clustering before t-testing on the same data, the t-test will be invalid, as its theory doesn't take into account that the data on which you test come from data dependent selection. (Although I admit that I'm not sure I fully understood what you tested there - differences between what?, so what's the null hypothesis, and how exactly was the test applied?) Chances are there is also an issue with the independence assumption if data from the same mouse was used without taking into account that information.

Comment: "how to choose the size of the bins" - how did you do that actually? My first advice would be to be guided by subject matter information, as far as this exists (which of course I don't know).

Comment: Thank you,
I'm not too familiar with the methods for estimating density, is this a non-parametric statistic?
Regarding "on the one hand there is no result when correcting for multiple tests" I know that the significance is not absolute, but the methods previously used generate a lot of testing and I am facing a lack power.
The null hypothesis after clustering is: H0 the average number of neurons in this cluster is equal in both groups.
Regarding the size of the bin, I chose it arbitrarily, hence the clustering to have a more objective construction